# How can i insert values based on a list of index?

Tags: python

this is the problem i am stumbling at.
i have a list

```
f = [2,4,8,10,72,52,50,65,100,85,15]

list_for_loop = [3,5,8]
```

how could i insert a value before the index based on this list (1st index excluded)?

i am now tring this:

```
for index in list_for_loop:
    if index ! = list_for_loop[0]:
         f[index].insert(0)
```

the result is different from what i expected because every time i insert a value the list index change

hopefully i can find a way to deal with the sliding index.
the ouput i expect:

```
f = [2,4,8,0,10,72,0,52,50,65,0,100,85,15]
```

Comment: *"the result is different from what i expected because every time i insert a value the list index change"* - Yeah right, as if that code ran at all.

Comment: I was trying to simplify the question. so i type the code i didn't run through there are some mistakes. thanks for the reminder :p

Comment: You are in the end expecting zeroes to end up in indices 3, 6, and 10, when the input says 3, 5, and 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd get your result by starting from the back and inserting from there:

```py
for i in reversed(list_for_loop):
    f.insert(i, 0)
```

As @Barmar states, if `list_for_loop` isn't in increasing order, then sort it in reverse:

```py
for i in sorted(list_for_loop, reverse=True):
    f.insert(i, 0)
```

Comment: In case `list_for_loop` isn't sorted, it would be better to sort it in reverse rather than just reverse it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Aplet-san. I am also having this same problem. Thank you for your efforts to help.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `list.insert` in a loop unnecessarily makes the solution *O(n x m)* in average time complexity, where *n* and *m* are the lengths of the two input lists, since the `list.insert` method has to move all items after the insertion index backwards to make room for the inserted item.

You can instead create a new list by iterating through the insertion indices, extending the new list with a slice of the main list at the insertion indices, and then appending the new value to the new list after each slice, so that the average time complexity is improved to a linear *O(n + m)*:

```
f = [2, 4, 8, 10, 72, 52, 50, 65, 100, 85, 15]
list_for_loop = [3, 5, 8]
new_f = []
for begin, end in zip((0, *list_for_loop), list_for_loop):
    new_f.extend(f[begin:end])
    new_f.append(0)
new_f.extend(f[end:])
print(new_f)
```

This outputs:

```
[2, 4, 8, 0, 10, 72, 0, 52, 50, 65, 0, 100, 85, 15]
```